# Saving aggregation results using $out, why does this not work?

Tags: linux, database, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to save the aggregation changes to a collection using $out.

```
db.emails.aggregate(
[
    {$addFields : {arr : {$objectToArray : "$$ROOT"}}}, 
    {$project : { pass : {$slice : ["$arr.v", 1, 20 ] }}} 
]

{
    $out :  "realEmails" 
}

)
```

Why does this not work?

Here is the error that I receive:

```
[thread1] SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list @(shell):7:0
```

Comment: Hi najer, and welcome to stack overflow. When you say it doesn't work, can you describe what is going wrong? Does it report an error, for example? Remember, on this site you're encouraged to [edit] your question to improve it as much as possible, as well as replying in the comments here.

Comment: @VinceBowdren If I knew what was going wrong, do you think I would be asking why it doesn't work?

Comment: What I meant was, can you describe _what_ is going wrong, i.e. the observed symptoms; I wasn't asking you to tell us _why_ it was going wrong i.e the root cause.

Comment: @VinceBowdren I have edited the original post with the error message I receive.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the out block inside the array.

```
 db.emails.aggregate([
    {$addFields : {arr : {$objectToArray : "$$ROOT"}}}, 
    {$project : { pass : {$slice : ["$arr.v", 1, 20 ] }}},
    {$out :  "realEmails"}
])
```